# What does "a processor independent API to XSLT transformations" mean?

Tags: php, xslt

I got this phrase in PHP manual page, but can't understand precisely.

Here is the link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.xslt.php

What's the association between XSLT processor and XSLT library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each XSLT library implements or interfaces a given XSLT processor. All libraries (should) support a given minimum API regardless of what XSLT processor it implements. This minimum API is what is referred to in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your explain about the association between XSLT processor and XSLT library, but I still can't understand "a processor independent API to XSLT transformations" clearly. Does it mean that it provides a unified interface for variety of XSLT processor?

Comment: Which part is still troubling you?

Comment: Does it mean that it provides a unified interface for variety of XSLT processor?

Comment: That is exactly what it means.